# A better way to add a meta box to custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, metabox

Id like to customize the UI for adding and editing a custom post type such that each custom field is included as a separate input field on the "new post" and "edit post" forms (as opposed to having to select them from the Custom Fields dropdown menu, as is the default).

Having looked around it appears that what Im looking for in known as a `meta_box` and the function to add one is `add_meta_box()`.

I found [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/rock-solid-wordpress-30-themes-using-custom-post-types--net-12093) tutorial which goes through the process of adding a custom post type and then a meta box - basically what I'm trying to do, but the code kinda sucks..

```
<?php

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_price');

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("prodInfo-meta", "Product Options", "meta_options", "product", "side", "low");
}

function meta_options(){
    
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $price = $custom["price"][0];
?>
    
    <label>Price:</label><input name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />

<?php
}

function save_price(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
}

?>
```

First of all, this guy is using the same name for one of the functions as the name of the hook `admin_init` - why would you do that??

Then I see the `admin-init` function calls `add_meta_box()` ..ok so far so good. But then `add_meta_box()` takes the `meta_options` function as one of the parameters and it looks like that function is what actually generates the input box by *manually echoing the input field html*. Then `save_price` manually appends the data from this field to the list of fields on submit.

Do I really have to go through this process for every single custom field on every single post type?

I feel like its not too much to ask to create a custom post type and have the ability to simply pass an array or something with custom field data and have those fields simply populate on the add and edit pages. Is that not possible? There's got to be a simpler and more scalable way to create a "meta_box", right?

Comment: There are plugins out there that make adding custom fields much easier, but there is no "Fields API" in WordPress that does what you describe (despite [much effort](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/14/fields-api-where-were-at/)). If you want to do it by hand, yes, you need to output the HTML for all inputs and handle saving them. There's nothing stopping you abstracting this yourself by creating an array of fields and then looping through them and outputting the right HTML.

Comment: The joy of open source is that if you feel something should work a different way you're fully empowered to change the way it works and add the functionality you want, and you can offer it back to the rest of the community who may find it useful! I understand that this might sound like a snarky answer, but I don't intend it that way - there are a *ton* of features and fixes Wordpress needs and people who can understand what they are and know how to build them are useful!

Comment: @mozboz doesnt sound snarky at all and I agree! I was actually thinking Id build this out as a robust feature and submit a PR but it appears, as the previous comment mentiones, that a fields API is already on the itinerary to be added to the WP core. Although maybe I write a plugin..